# What is the best way to record UISwitch state in UserDefaults in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I have a settings view in my (future) app, with 4 UISwitch. I want to use the UserDefaults class to record the switches state.

I created a struct "SettingsKey" with 4 properties (keys) to save each switch state :

```
struct SettingsKeys {
  static let appShowContactsPhoto = "app.showContactsPhoto"
  static let appShowAge = "app.showAge"
  static let widgetShowContactsPhoto = "widget.showContactsPhoto"
  static let widgetShowAge = "widget.showAge"
}
```

To load the data, I use 4 "UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: key)" for the 4 properties in SettingsKeys, in the "viewDidLoad" method.

What is the best way to save the data? I don't want to create 4 actions in my view controller (one "valueChanged" action for each switch), so I just created one. But how to map each UISwitch with the righ "SettingsKey" property? I want a generic code (one instruction?), I don't want my code to be like this :

```
if sender = switch1 then record data with this key
else if sender = switch2 then record data with this key
else if ...
```

Maybe with the UIView tags?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can use Tag or accisibilitylabel

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
@IBAction func changeSettings(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
        // Change for switch1

        break
    case 2:
        // Change for switch2

        break
    case 3:
        // Change for switch3, etc
        break

    default:
        print("Unknown Switch")
        return
    }

}
```

You can set the Tags(**Unique Number to identify your view/Switch**).

(**In Above example they are 1, 2 3**) respectively for each switch.

Answer (score 0):

I used the UIView.tag property, as proposed by wolverine :

- 1st UISwitch.tag = 0
- 2nd UISwitch.tag = 1
- ...

Then I modified my structure :

```
struct SettingsKeys {
  // Application Settings
  static let appShowContactsPhoto = "app.showContactsPhoto"
  static let appShowAge = "app.showAge"

  // Widget Settings
  static let widgetShowContactsPhoto = "widget.showContactsPhoto"
  static let widgetShowAge = "widget.showAge"

  // All settings
  static let serialized = [
    0: appShowContactsPhoto,
    1: appShowAge,
    10: widgetShowContactsPhoto,
    11: widgetShowAge,
  ]
}
```

My action :

```
// Click on a switch button
@IBAction func changeSetting(_ sender: UISwitch) {
  UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, SettingsKeys.serialized[sender.tag]!)
}
```

It works fine!

Comment: One suggestion : I am sure you are going to use 4 switch and to them you are going to use this IBAction. But also check that the Tags you receiving is proper. If another developer works and make any changes in Sotryboard or code, there will be possibility of crash. Just a suggestion.